# Can't make NetworkManagerQt work in manjaro

Tags: c++, qt, manjaro

I have a problem activating the NetworkManagerQt in Qt 6.4. My S.O is Manjaro.
I have installed NetworkManager and NetworkManager-qt. When I execute the this command:

```
locate networkmanager
```

I can see that networkmanagerqt can be found under the directory */usr/include/KF5/NetworkManagerQt*.

I don't know how to add NetworkManagerQt to my project. If I simply try to add a header (e.g: #include <NetworkManagerQt/AccessPoint>), I get the "file not found" error. I've tried to add in my .pro file the following lines:

```
LIBS += -lNetworkManagerQt

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += networkmanager-qt
```

But doesn't seem to solve anything, the error persist. Plus, when trying to add the third line, I get the error: ":-1: error: Project ERROR: networkmanager-qt development package not found", which seems unfixable because I can't find a way to install networkmanager-qt development package.

Any help on how to solve this or where I can find more information is really appreciated.

Thanks to all in advance.

**UPDATE:**

After some research and asking in forums, I found out that there's a website that contains manjaro's package list (I'm pretty new to Manjaro, been using it for only a couple days). So, I saw [here](https://packages.manjaro.org/?query=networkmanager) that there's no Qt6 version of networkmanager-Qt available yet and, as I'm using Qt 6.4, I resorted to using NetworkManager through QDBus. It was a little difficult at first but I managed to make everything work. Having said that, the tips provided below by zkoza where helpful. If anyone is having this problem and wants to solve it, those tips are a good place to start from.

Comment: I think `QT += NetworkManagerQt` should be enough

Comment: if I add that line, I get ":-1: error: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: NetworkManagerQt"

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
find_package(KF5NetworkManagerQt)
target_link_libraries(your_app_name KF5NetworkManagerQt)
```

should do the trick.

In Manjaro the cmake files for `NetworkManagerQt`are located at `/usr/lib/cmake/KF5NetworkManagerQt/` rather than the in usual location `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/`, so you may need to help cmake find it.

See:

- [NetworkManagerQt](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/networkmanager-qt/html/index.html) documentation
- [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) documentation

---

EDIT:

Generally, in Manjaro the library is installed as
`/usr/lib/libKF5NetworkManagerQt.so`

so I guess if you use make and `*.pro` file project definitions, you need

```
LIBS += -lKF5NetworkManagerQt
```

In Manjaro, you can list all the files included in any package via the `pamac` package manager, e.g.:

```
pamac list --files networkmanager-qt
```

which will tell you where the `*.h` and `*.so` files are or will be installed and under which names.

Comment: Can I use this even though I'm using qmake instead of cmake?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow thought you can use cmake.  I've added some extra explanation.

Comment: Thanks! I added the line you suggested, but still Qt isn't finding the NetworkManagerQt files. Should I add the location of NetworkManagerQt to the .pro file? 
The *.h files are in /usr/include/KF5/NetworkManagerQt. In this directory I have two folders, both named NetworkManagerQt, one containing the *.h files and the other c source code. Then, the *.so files are located in /usr/lib. What should I do now?

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: try adding `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/KF5/NetworkManagerQt/`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just tried it and I think It could kinda work with some troubleshooting, although I read that there's no Qt6 version of networkmanager-Qt available yet. So I just resorted to using QDBus. In a way I think it's better because the installation of this software on other systems will be easier, as I won't have to install NetworkManagerQt in every device. The downside is that the code is a little complex but it works like a charm.
Again, thank you for your time!

Comment: Manjaro has the `networkmanager-qt6` package in the arch users' repository that should be Qt6 compatible.